# Spatio Temporal Interpolation with gstat in R

Tags: r, spatio-temporal-data, variogram, gstat

I am very new to spatial evaluation and come from psychology.

I am using the software R and the packages "gstat" and "spacetime".

I would like to do a spatio temporal interpolation. For this I follow the paper of Gräler et al. (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gstat/vignettes/spatio-temporal-kriging.pdf)

Unfortunately I can't find/fit the right variogram model.  I can create the empirical variogram and this is also conclusive to me, but then I do not get any further. I do not understand how to define the individual parameters such as "sill" or "nugget" or what they stand for.

Here are my previous approaches:

My ST-Dataframe:

```
> df.stf
An object of class "STFDF"
Slot "data":
# A tibble: 2,406 x 6
     KRS month DeprIndex MMW10 MMW25 NewInfect
   <dbl> <int>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
 1  1001     1    -4.08   NA   NA           NA
 2  1002     1    -2.28   13.3 NA           NA
 3  1003     1    -3.29   17.8 11.7         NA
 4  1004     1    -4.31   NA   NA           NA
 5  1051     1    -2.51   17.7 NA           NA
 6  1053     1    -1.07   13.0  9.93        NA
 7  1054     1    -0.863  NA   NA           NA
 8  1055     1    -1.63   NA   NA           NA
 9  1056     1     0.887  NA   NA           NA
10  1057     1    -1.21   14.7  8.84        NA
# ... with 2,396 more rows

Slot "sp":
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 401 
extent      : 3280359, 3921536, 5237511, 6103443  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs         : +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=9 +k=1 +x_0=3500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=598.1,73.7,418.2,0.202,0.045,-2.455,6.7 +units=m +no_defs 
variables   : 1
names       :   AGS 
min values  :  1001 
max values  : 16077 

Slot "time":
           timeIndex
0001-01-30         1
0002-01-30         2
0003-01-30         3
0004-01-30         4
0005-01-30         5
0006-01-30         6

Slot "endTime":
[1] "0002-01-30 CET" "0003-01-30 CET" "0004-01-30 CET" "0005-01-30 CET" "0006-01-30 CET" "0007-01-30 CET"
```

So, I have 401 german counties and the mean monthly PM10 value over six month.

My empirical variogram:

```
eVgmPm10<-variogramST(MMW10~1,df.stf,tlags = 0:5)

eVgmPm10$dist<-eVgmPm10$dist/1000
eVgmPm10$avgDist  <- eVgmPm10$avgDist/1000
eVgmPm10$spacelag <- eVgmPm10$spacelag/1000

plot(eVgmPm10, map=F)
```

[image: empirical variogram]

So far everything works as it should (I guess)

Now I wanted to make as in the paper explained a seperable model:

```
separableModel <- vgmST("separable",
                        space = vgm(0.9, "Exp", 200, 0.1),
                        time = vgm(0.9, "Sph", 3.5, 0.1),
                        sill = 124)
```

I understand, that I have to create a variogram for space and time. But I do not know how to define the parameters correctly (psill, model, range, nugget) for the variograms. If I use the same parameters as in the paper I get folowing plot:

[image: Plot empircal and separable model]

As you can see, in this model, I just have two lags and the variogram looks realy strange. So, I think it is because of the wrong parameter for my model. I also tested another approach like in the paper.

```
sumMetricModel <- vgmST("sumMetric",
                        space = vgm(20, "Sph", 150, 1),
                        time = vgm(10, "Exp", 2, 0.5),
                        joint = vgm(80, "Sph", 1500, 2.5),
                        stAni = 120)
```

Again, I do not have any idea and clue how to set the parameters so I took the same as in the paper and plot all three.

[image: empirical, separable, sum metric]

[image: wireframe of all three]

I am pretty sure it depend on the parameters but I do really not know how to find the correct variogram model to fit.

Comment: see [Fitting variogram models in gstat](https://www.r-spatial.org/r/2016/02/14/gstat-variogram-fitting.html)

Comment: Thank you for the very helpfull link! From your link I know how to choose the "range" but as the space-time-object I don't know how to get the "psill" and the "nugget" which are means but means of what?

Comment: @AriWhatElse you need to fit a theoretical model (exponential, circular, spherical whatever) to the empirical variogram to estimate the parameters range, psill and nugget. See this post: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225840/how-do-i-get-the-fitted-values-and-or-residuals-in-fit-variogram-function-of-g/226150#226150

Comment: @Guzmán thank you for you answer! It helped me a bit but actually it is not the answer i searched for. I understand the variogram model if I just take the space in account but my issue is more the spatiotemporal variogram. I know that the range is the distance where the model first flattens out. And the sill is the value at this distance. The nugget is normaly 0 but sometimes you need to set the nugget on the value where the curve cut the y-axis. My issue is I said more the combination of space and time. What is the range of time? What is the sill of time? and so on. But anyway thank you a lot

Comment: @AriWhatElse Why didn't you ever used the function `fit.StVariogram` from `gstat` to estimate the parameters you want for the space and time variograms that seems is what you want? It seems that the function `vgmST` only have dummy values or seeds. Then with `fit.StVariogram`  you find the parameters.

Comment: @Guzmán to use `fit.StVariorgam` I need a desired spatio-temporal model which I get through `vgmST`.